# AMD OpenGL ES SDK setup

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I installed [AMD OpenGL ES SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/) to be able to develop ES2 programs.The SDK has a demo included.I tried to run the demo and got an error here:

```
EGLDisplay eglDisplay;
eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(nativeDisplay);
```

That's 
line 214 in main.cpp .The error is "access violation executing location".Now, the nativeDisplay appears as not initialized.It's initialization happens a couple of lines above within the following block:

```
    EGLNativeDisplayType nativeDisplay;
if(!OpenNativeDisplay(&nativeDisplay))
{
    printf("Could not get open native display\n");
    return GL_FALSE;
}
```

And indeed,when I open OpenNativeDisplay() method all I see inside is this:

```
  bool OpenNativeDisplay(EGLNativeDisplayType* nativedisp_out)
 {
    *nativedisp_out = (EGLNativeDisplayType) NULL;
    return true;
 }
```

Is it kind of SDK bug or it should be like that intentionally? My system is Windows 764bit.Using VisualStudio 2010 express with VC10 compiler.And my GPU is NVidia GeForce GT 630M

Comment: Im assuming you actually have an AMD video card?  The fact that you have an NVidia graphics card could be your problem!!!  This is an AMD driver!

Comment: Nope.You mean the SDK is only usable with AMD card?

Comment: That could be indeed it.  Go http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/ and look at the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: Hmm,yes,but don't you find weird the fact that OpenNativeDisplay returns nativedisp_out always as null pointer ?

Comment: Not really, if the true driver doesn't know how to actually access the video card that your monitor is connected to (because it is connected to an NVidia card), then no I don't.  I hope this helps, another way to test would be to try and install a similar setup on a computer that HAS an AMD card, and see if it works!

Comment: Well,don't have AMD cards at all.Thanks for the input anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use this SDK in your situation, it will not work with NV GPUs. AMD actually implements EGL at the driver level (you can see this if you look at the export table for atioglxx.dll), where as NV does not.

[image]

For an NV solution, consider the ES2 profile extension: [`WGL_EXT_create_context_es2_profile`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/wgl_create_context_es2_profile.txt) and use the traditional WGL window system instead of EGL. It is not a perfect match by any means, but it is the best you can do on NV GPUs.

By the way, if you read the bottom of the first section you linked to for AMD's SDK it basically tells you what I just did:

> Typically, emulators or translation layers are required to develop and execute OpenGL ES application in desktop environments, but with this SDK, AMD provides fully compliant native support for OpenGL ES 2 and EGL on systems running AMD Radeon™ HD, AMD Mobility Radeon™ HD, and AMD FirePro™ graphics cards.

Comment: Well,I finally went with PowerVR SDK .That one works with any GPU.THanks for the info though.

Comment: So you don't actually need a native implementation of EGL/GLES2 then? The PowerVR SDK includes an emulator.

Comment: I am not sure if PowerVR is native or not as I see in the demo code it actually creates context via EGL (using win32 window) .I am mostly interested in porting my 3d framework to be compatible with ES2